# Plotly.js, show tooltips outside of chart container

Tags: d3.js, plotly, plotly.js

I need to implement a plotly.js chart on a page with a very restricted width. As a result, a tooltip is partially cut. Is it possible to cause tooltip not to be limited by plotly.js container size?

[image]

My code example at codepen: https://codepen.io/anatoly314/pen/gOavXzZ?editors=1111

```
//my single trace defined as following but it's better to see example at codepen
const yValue1 = [1000];
const trace1 = {
        x: [1],
        y: yValue1,
        name: `Model 1`,
        text: yValue1.map(value => Math.abs(value)),
        type: 'bar',
        textposition: 'outside'
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, by design, not possible for any part of the chart to overflow its container.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is wrong to say that by design this is not possible! It is a bit hacky, but when you add the following lines, it shows the label outside of svg:

```
svg.main-svg,svg.main-svg *
{
  overflow:visible !important;
}
```

Comment: This works great! In my case, I had an additional complication in that the overflowed content was getting clipped by adjacent canvas elements (multiple side-by-side charts in my situation) that follow the chart showing the tooltip. This is because the overflowing tooltip receives the same z-index as its canvas, and the next canvas has a higher stacking order since it appears later in the DOM. This was easily solved by elevating the z-index of the canvas current showing a tooltip by using a :hover style rule. Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by rokdd works. However the css selector should be more specific, otherwise it's natural that you will introduce subtle bugs (particularly if you need to scroll the content where the plotly chart is contained).

If we look at the DOM tree constructed by Plotly, we find that the tooltips are created inside the `<g class="hoverlayer"></g>` element (which is a direct child of one of the three `<svg class="main-svg"></svg>`). So that parent (that `svg.main-svg` element) is only one that needs to affected.

The ideal css selector in this case would be the `:has` selector. However it's still not supported (as of 2022): https://css-tricks.com/the-css-has-selector/

So the next simplest thing is to use a little bit of javascript right after we call `Plotly.newPlot`:

```js
// get the correct svg element
var mainSvgEl = document.querySelector('#positive g.hoverlayer').parentElement;
mainSvgEl.style['overflow'] = 'visible';
```

Or in a more generic way (works for any chart):

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('g.hoverlayer')).forEach(hoverEl => {
  let mainSvgEl = hoverEl.parentElement;
  mainSvgEl.style['overflow'] = 'visible';
});
```